# Rotated Text via Canvas Rotation off angle

Tags: java, android

I am creating a graph for which I need an axis title for the y axis.

The problem is I need it at -90 degress to the horizontal.

Here is how I rotate the text at the moment.

```
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(-90,15,viewHeight/2+20);
    canvas.drawText(yAxisTitle,15,viewHeight/2+20, paint);
    canvas.restore();
```

The problem is once its rotated its not straight on the vertical. Its as if its going too far?

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Comment: I like your thinking @blackbelt but no joy

Comment: I have the same issue. I rotate the canvas by 90 degrees, then drawText. On six different devices, the text looks ok, on two it's a little rotated, or rather, the characters are upright but they drop a little towards the end of the text. As if each character is drawn one pixel lower than the previous one.

Comment: My solution is the following: I draw a background bitmap, then text. Instead of rotating the canvas then draw bitmap and text on canvas, I first draw the text on the bitmap (on its canvas), then rotate the canvas, then draw the bitmap on the rotated canvas. then the characters are straight. If you don't have a background image, you can create a transparent bitmap, use that as background, and draw the text on that before rotating the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it appeared to just be occurring on the emulator. Testing on 4 devices all displayed the text at the correct angle?!

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. I have the same issue on a device, not an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

mine `onDraw()` in a `TextView` subclass:

```
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
        canvas.rotate(-90);
        Layout layout = getLayout();
        if (layout != null)
            layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
```

in ordert to put text use `setText()`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the following: I draw a background bitmap, then text. Instead of rotating the canvas then draw bitmap and text on canvas, I first draw the text on the bitmap (on its canvas), then rotate the canvas, then draw the bitmap on the rotated canvas. then the characters are straight. If you don't have a background image, you can create a transparent bitmap, use that as background, and draw the text on that before rotating the canvas.